# Which type of diagram should I use (infrastructural)?

Tags: uml, diagram

I am trying to figure out which kind of diagram, I need to use. It's kind of an simplification of the infrastructure, which should show how the IdP is securing my test application (with a firewall in front).

So I am thinking of creating my own style, just for showing the concept. On the other hand I am searching for a standard, which shows the components in the infrastructure and how they interact with each other (Start: the browser calls for the application)

Comment: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams-overview.html

Comment: and https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html for looking into the system's guts.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

1. A UML Component model, to illustrate the structure of your software components, and
2. A UML Deployment model, to illustrate how the software is deployed to hardware and what hardware nodes (including your firewall) are required.